# Is it possible to update existing issues with sourcemaps in sentry?

Tags: typescript, source-maps, sentry

We are using self-host Sentry - https://sentry.io/ for logging frontend errors.

We are uploading sourcemaps using:

`sentry-cli releases files demo@sentry-test upload-sourcemaps dist/demo --rewrite --verbose --validate`

It works perfectly for all new issues. Exceptions are shown with sourcemaps.

But we would like to see sourcemaps in existing issues. I supposed that when I upload sourcemaps also existing issues will be updated too. But they'r not. There is still minified code shown.

When same issue appear again, it shows source code. But we would like to see it also on old issues.

Filenames in uploaded artefacts are correct.
[image]

New issue shows sourcecode correctly

[image]

Old issues doesn't
[image]

I have simulated it with this steps:

1) application is built with sourcemaps
2) exception is logged to sentry
3) sourcemaps uploaded
4) same exception is logged to sentry

Result: first exception doesn't have sourcemaps, second one does.

Sentry is using sourcemaps in time of logging exception.

Is it possible to update details of existing issues somehow, by running some job to reprocess it?

I would appreciate your production experience.

Comment: You need to provide some more information, keep in mind people do not have insight to your world. Try to publish an example of what works and what doesn't

Comment: @DoronG thank you for your response, I supposed that everyone who have experiece With Sentry will understand, I have added images, and remove unnecessary technological details. 

It is only about how and when sentry connects new issues to sourcemaps. And if is possible to reprocess old ones.

Comment: Well easiest would be to use npm like package registry to host your private package and use url like jsdeliver.net, e.g cdn.jsdeliver.net/npm/package/version/.... , this way every published version will become readonly forever and your page should reference full versioned url. This will remove all issues related to source map mismatch. There are plenty of free package hosting available such as ProGet, verdaccio etc

Comment: @AkashKava sorry, but you are not answering my question. It has nothing to do with package management.

Comment: @VíťaPlšek-angular.cz how are different versions of the same file are identified in URL? Try to understand from Sentry's perspective, it looks like sentry is taking new source maps, but how can it fetch old ones? When you upload new files, old files are retained?

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Url and filenames are identical.
Screenshots are from isolated behaviour - 1) I have built application with sourcemaps. 2) Provided exception which is logged in sentry. 3) Then uploaded sourcemaps 4) Provided same exception again . The first logged exception doesnt contain sourcemaps, the second one does. Sentry probably parse sourcemaps in the time of logging exception and after that the information is cached. My question is - is possible to reprocess existing issues?

Comment: I came into a similar scenario. Sentry issue is created before source map uploaded ( CI sentry release job failed, but webapp already deployed ). Wonder if it is possible to reprocess the existed issue after "sentry-release" fixed

Comment: Was this resolved din any way?